# How can I track hits to areas of my web application?

Tags: web-applications, analytics

We have a growing web application, and we currently use Google Analytics and Chartbeat to track usage and engagement (although we're open to alternatives). Unfortunately, both are geared towards content-based sites where everything is about the URL. Our URLs contain object IDs, making them less useful independently, and causing us to grow beyond Google Analytics' 50,000 unique URLs per day.

How can we track hits to areas of our web application, essentially ignoring parts of the URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to customise your tracking code to replace the URL with the part of the site that the user is using:

```
  // Replace this with what you want to use instead of the URL 
  var applicationArea = "/login-area"; 

  // GA Tracking Code
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', applicationArea]);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Comment: That's not bad. I'll dig into this solution a little more and see if it yields something for us. Thanks!